# Does "Map Remote" in Charles Proxy work with iOS devices?

Tags: remote-debugging

I am trying to redirect traffic for my production site to test server through Charles Proxy on my iPhone using the "Map Remote" function, is this possible?  If not, is there any alternative that will allow redirect mapping on iOS devices?